# Are typedefed types always visible for derived classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, types, namespaces, typedef

If I `typedef` some types in a base class in public, Does the C++ standard guarantee the `typedef`ed types are always visible for derived classes?

For example:

```
struct A
{
    typedef int T;
};

struct B : A
{
    void f(T) {}; // Does the C++ standard guarantee it can be compiled?
};

int main()
{
    B().f(8); 
}
```

Comment: It can be hidden, e.g. `struct B : A { int T;  void f(T) {}  /* error */ };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typedef`s defined in a class have the same access rules as other names of a class. The usual access rules for `private`, `protected`, and `public` names apply to `typedef`s as well.

From the draft standard n3337:

**7.1.3 The `typedef` Specifier**

1. ... Within the scope of its declaration, a *typedef-name* is syntactically equivalent to a keyword and names the type associated with the identifier in the way described in Clause 8.

**9.2 Class Members**

1. The *member-specification* in a class definition declares the full set of members of the class; no member can be added elsewhere. Members of a class are data members, member functions (9.3), nested types, and enumerators. Data members and member functions are static or non-static; see 9.4. Nested types are classes (9.1, 9.7) and enumerations (7.2) defined in the class, and arbitrary types declared as members by use of a typedef declaration (7.1.3).

Comment: Could you refer us to the pages of the C++ standard?

Comment: @xmllmx I think you're looking for [class.access.base] 11.2/1.